how could I solve the knight's tour problem
I'm trying to solve the knight's tour and here is my code. I don't know why it runs too strange
I don't know why the recursive not work
pls helppp me :<<<<
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int dx[] = { 2,1,-1,-2,-2,-1,1,2 };
int dy[] = { 1,2,2,1,-1,-2,-2,-1 };

int** crchestboard(int r, int c);
void knight(int x, int y, int **board, int r,int c,int step);
void coutb(int **board, int r, int c);

int main() {
    int step = 1;
    int r,c,x,y;
    cin >> r >> c;
    int** chestboard = crchestboard(r,c);
    cin >> x >> y;
    knight(x, y, chestboard,r,c, step);
}

int **crchestboard(int r, int c) {
    int **chestboard = new int* [r];
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        chestboard[i] = new int[c];
    }
    return chestboard;
}

void knight(int x, int y,int **board, int r,int c,int step) {
    if (step>=r*c) {
        coutb(board,r,c);
    }
    else {
        //available steps
        for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
            //find available moves
            int xx = x + dx[i];
            int yy = y + dy[i];
            //knight have to move in board

            if (xx >= 0 && yy >= 0 && xx < r &&yy <c) {
                if (board[xx][yy] == 0)//moved?
                {
                    board[xx][yy] = step;
                    knight(xx,yy,board,r,c,step+1);
                    board[xx][yy] = 0;//back
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
void coutb(int** board, int r, int c) {
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
            cout << board[i][j] << "\t";
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
    
}

the recursive doesn't work and it doesn't return the chestboard so I don't know what happen with it
:<

dx[8] is an out-of-range reference and leads to undefined behaviour.

@trincot agreed that it should be i < 8 for indexing knights moves. But I think the contents of the chessboard not being initialised to zero is probably the more fundamental mistake here. OP might want to try running it on a 4x4 board and following the execution in a debugger. I don't think it is too far off working.

The i <= 8 in the for loop should probably be i < 8 (just something that caught my eye, I didn't read all the code in details).
